# Stack Exchange cross tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is it possible (or a good feature to have) to search or tag questions with Stack Exchange subdomains?

For example, a question on drupal.stackexchange.com tagged with "serverfault" could be searchable from the community on serverfault.com, or the drupal.stackexchange.com community could find their CMS related questions.

Comment: This is a question that suits better the General meta site, as it involves the full Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Hmm, better cross site search would be awesome, this I don't really think so

Comment: Related (nearly dupe if not for the tag part) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration

Comment: I think there would be many improper tags. Users of other sites would likely not appreciate an excess of tags, especially since most questions are relevant to one site. If this is started, though, I recommend putting a rep minimum to cross-tag. That would prevent many improper cross tags.

Comment: Do you have any examples of an exemplary question or two that would be on topic both in drupal and serverfault for example? The beauty of narrow focus is that questions get tailored for the specific site they are asked. I don't see how institutionalizing cross posting of the same content (or working around this) would be of wide use, but perhaps there are some good examples that would illustrate your point?