# Create new "interesting" tab to aggregate interesting posts from all registered SE sites

Tags: feature-request

On Academia.SE, we often have questions which are best answered by our site, but which are highly relevant to other sites such as [math](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/670/skimming-through-a-math-paper-with-a-group), [biology](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-are-alternatives-to-journal-of-theoretical-biology), [physics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/941/publishing-amateur-research), [cogsci](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/what-is-a-fair-metric-for-assessing-the-citation-impact-of-journals-across-disci), and occasionally even [tex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/941/publishing-amateur-research). Most of these questions are a poor fit on their main site, but as most subject matter experts are there, there's a far better chance of them getting a good answer at that site. Most posters try to "solve" this problem by cross-posting, which has all of the negatives and none of the positives; it's closed on the subject-specific site as off-topic, and ignored on the broader due to low expertise.

The current solution is to simply encourage users to remain active on multiple sites. The problem is that there's no easy* way to view questions you're interested in across multiple sites.

That being said, it would be useful if there was a view which would be functionally identical to the "interesting" tab, except that it would cover the entire network, and not just a single site. It would highlight recent questions from tags you frequent (determined automatically) on each site at which you have registered, and provide a useful dashboard for questions that are interesting *to you* across the whole network.

---

* Yes, users can [create a custom filtered query on the main stackexchange site](https://stackexchange.com/filters/26652/my-filter). This is not "easy", as it requires knowledge that the functionality exists and the willingness to write and maintain a query with all tags you're interested in across X sites.

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration