# Are cross-site duplicate Meta questions subjected to closure?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, per-site-meta

The title of my question is quite self-explanatory. Does asking a duplicate question on two or three different Meta sites actually subject them being labelled **duplicate** and **closed** by reputed users of Stack Exchange or corresponding Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to close a question on site X as duplicate of a question on site Y. That is true for main sites and meta sites alike. See e.g. [Could we allow child Meta questions to be closed as duplicates of Meta.SE ones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229870/295232)

That said, I *have* seen questions being closed on per-site metas (as <s>off-topic</s> A community specific reason) because the community felt it was better to discuss matters on Meta Stack Exchange (or, in rarer cases, e.g. questions about a bad migration, another per-site meta).