# Is there an easy way to get here from the meta sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, per-site-meta

Some questions that address basically the software behind SE sites seem to appear sooner or later on every meta site. But they have already an answer [here on **META**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)...

Would it be possible to make the META contents more accessible?<sup>[1]</sup>

(for example by providing alternative links in empty search results on local meta sites)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I'm not totally sure whether I understand the user interface right, but I found the link to META only in the footer area.

Comment: Agreed. I would like to have a link added to the "help" menu in the top bar, only in meta sites, below the "What's meta" link.

Comment: [This feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171655/make-network-wide-faq-posts-available-on-per-site-metas) is my own take on the same problem. I don't think all the posts should be available, just the important FAQ ones.

Comment: @MadScientist selected via a `general-faq` tag?

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is one location where I expected it

Comment: Another option is to have the [main FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) always displayed in per site meta Community Bulletin. (the box with links on top of the sidebar)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you mean a link to it (with text 'main FAQ')