# Allow moderators to add local guidance to the "how to ask a good question" page in the help center

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, help-center

The help center includes some good advice on [how to ask a good question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  This is good baseline advice for all sites, and this page is the same across the network.

Some sites have developed additional guidance, like the [Stack Overflow checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/922300), [Worldbuilding's questions to think about](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3624/28), Workplace's posts on 
[professionalism](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2979/325) and [globalization](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3216/325), and Christianity's [guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/4145) (from a site that has a lot of trouble with out-of-scope questions from first-time askers).  At least one site also has a flowchart for asking questions.

Could moderators please have the ability to *add to* the basic help-center page, much like we can edit the first paragraph of the tour but not the whole thing?  I don't want to see sites completely forking the page (and thus losing the benefit of future updates that get pushed out), but it sure would be nice to have one paragraph where we could edit in site-specific links.

Comment: Related: [We have better advice for answerers in our “On topic” page than our “How to answer” page.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6286/4398)

Comment: @BESW yes, several sites would benefit from having a "how to answer" page in the help center alongside the "how to ask" one.  (Back-it-up rules, what kinds of sources are welcome, respecting the political/geographical/genre/theological/etc constraints of the question, etc.)

Comment: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/882/6962

Comment: Once again it would be great to have this implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279879/improved-help-center-site-specific-pages-and-site-specific-edits-to-all-pages