# Achievements dropdown and profile don't agree on rep change from removed user

Tags: bug, reputation, users, achievements-dialog

I happened to notice this in the rep-change dropdown list:

[image: user removed, -5]

This is the only "user removed" event shown here on that site on that day.  (You'll just have to trust me on that; the whole list of events for the day doesn't fit in the container.)  However, look at this from the reputation tab of my profile:

[image: reputation tab shows -10]

Both agree on the total rep change for the day; it's just that one shows -5 and the other shows -10 for a removed user.  I wasn't paying enough attention to know which is the real change.

I'm not bothered by the event (these things happen; no sense trying to figure out the details, and anyway it's only 5 or 10 rep).  But I don't think I've seen a mismatch like this before, and the hobgoblin of little minds demanded that I report this apparent bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out what happened - in the Achievements dropdown, the code that rolls up rep changes per post for a given time bucket doesn't differentiate which kind of rep events it groups together.

In this case, the user that was deleted had upvoted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280428/allow-moderators-to-add-local-guidance-to-the-how-to-ask-a-good-question-page); there are 15 other rep events (e.g. upvotes and downvotes) in that time bucket on that same question, so the "user was removed" event type was overwritten.

The user profile's rep tab keeps "user was removed" events separate from the other types.

Some kind of fix will be pushed out to sync these two views.

Comment: Was this fixed?