# Reputation discrepancy in achievements dialogue after user removal

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, achievements-dialog, reputation-history

So today the "User was removed" happened but there's a difference between the reputation loss shown in the achievements dialogue (shows -70) and the reputation history in the user profile (shows -80).

[image: screenshot of achievements dialogue and user profile reputation tab]

I found a [previous bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280464) that seems similar. rev 2022.6.8.42312

Comment: Is there something about this which makes you believe it's not [just caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: @Makyen excellent link, but  after 2 hours I wouldn't be so fast to blame caching. I also searched through the previous MSE posts and there's only 1 very similar instance to this one (the others being about rep caps and +2 edits) so it was worth posting.

Comment: It seems to be the same cause as [Why does it incorrectly say I lost 8,000 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336460/why-does-it-incorrectly-say-i-lost-8-000-rep)

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog it's different because that one's about the 60 day rule of keeping rep of deleted posts. (The numbers involved also don't make the other post clear enough for the average user IMO.)

Comment: This post is about a user removal overlaping with the rep cap long after the fact (coinciding with a removal on at least 2 sites).

Comment: @Rob also not, everything about that post seems to indicate different factors -and more confusing- were at play in how the reputation was added (the OP says it themselves at the end of the post). The target duplicate also doesn't have an answer and much less by staff, so if anything the closure should be done the other way around (but I still think the questions are different).

Comment: @bad CV retracted.

Comment: @bad_coder The target does have a staff *comment* that also covers this issue, plus the answer there quotes that comment.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog I already explained the posts are obviously different no deleted post is involved in this thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When votes are invalidated, whether you actually lose reputation depends on when that vote was originally cast. If you were rep-capped that day, the vote being invalidated won't actually cause your reputation to change - you'll be compensated for it by having a +10 assigned to the next upvote that day. So that day will now display as having earned 210 instead of 200, with the -10 today setting it back to 200.

For accounting purposes, that vote that didn't change your reputation is still listed in your reputation history to make the overall math work out. **But you only actually lost 70 reputation, not 80.** According to the log, your reputation dropped form 18,853 to 18,783 with the recalculation.

What you're seeing in your reputation history is a, let's say, interesting way of trying to convey that. It separated the "User was removed" event into two different ones for a reason. It wasn't two users that got removed. It was 7 upvotes that actually caused -10 each and 1 upvote that was compensated by other votes. The reputation dialog is correct in the sense that it is displaying your net loss for these events. The reputation history is correct in the sense that it is displaying the complete history of everything.

This is also not specific to deleted users - it would occur with any invalidation or other events that would cause rep-cap oddities on older days.

Comment: A similar issue was previously filed for reputation lost to a normally deleted post, which I've voted to close this question as a duplicate of. Is that the same cause as this?