# WordPress Answers or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation, wordpress-se

With the advent of the WordPress Answers Stack Exchange site, there's undoubtedly going to be overlap.  But I just want to get some advice:

I'm a developer and I kinda hate WordPress, but have to use it occasionally. My WordPress questions are usually development ones (when I have them), and most often related to 'how WordPress handles things', which are pretty obvious in straight programming terms.  But with the WordPress layer of abstraction, they become problematic.

I find that most developers that have gone near WordPress are usually also PHP/JS/CSS/MYSQL guys who dabble with WordPress and, as a result, hangout more on SO. And theres a die hard bunch who are heavy into the WP.SE site, but generally the WP site is for people trying to muddle through the day to day operation of using WordPress and its many themes/plugin etc.

As a result, if I were to ask something pretty in-depth about writing / integrating new & strange features or something, I'm talking to a much smaller group of devs than I would be on SO.

**So, enough of the ramble, my question:**

Should I be posting heavy development questions relating to WordPress on the WP.SE site or to SO? Can I post to both, or is cross posting frowned upon in these cases still?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I be posting heavy dev questions relating to wordpress on the WP.SE site or to SO? Can I post to both or is cross posting frowned upon in these cases still?

In my experience, you're definitely going to get better feedback on WP.SE even with heavily developer-oriented questions. The site has many members who understand the internals of Wordpress, so ideally you'll get a good answer there, and won't have a need to cross-post (which indeed is kinda frowned upon).

Comment: yep, I do get that but there's a much smaller amount of them.. I'm just trying to figure out where the balance lies. there's prob 10-100x the amount of php devs for example on SO and 50% of them at some point have come across WP and might be able to help.

Comment: @Alex sure, but I've had some pretty deep WP questions that found a good solution on WP.SE... I'd try it first, and if it doesn't yield anything, shamefacedly cross-post. :) Or try it the other way round

Comment: so basically try the WP site first and if noone cares then try SO :-)

Comment: @Alex yeah, pretty much :)