# How can I follow questions on a topic (like Facebook) across multiple sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, migration

I just read: [What is the best site to ask Facebook questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136560/what-is-the-best-stack-to-ask-facebook-questions) Thanks to gobernador, I just learned that SO has a site for Facebook. This butts up to: [WordPress Answers or Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136577/wordpress-answers-or-stack-overflow) While we canhave a debate on how dynamic FB is to WP, or vis versa, should questions be pushed to their sites or are things getting too specific?

Comment: SO has a "site" for Facebook... not really. It's just a subdomain that filters questions with the [tag:facebook] tag, not a separate site.

Comment: hmm, I did a search on so for [tag:facebook] and the questions were different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *programming* questions about Facebook, you can ask on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ - this isn't really a *separate site*, merely a custom "view" of Stack Overflow with an emphasis on Facebook questions. Note that "programming" means "developing an app that connects with Facebook's APIs in some way". As with the rest of Stack Overflow, [the FAQ applies](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

For questions on *using* Facebook, ask on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

For support questions, see: http://www.facebook.com/help/ - Stack Exchange does not and cannot provide answers about problems with your account, billing, etc.

Comment: See my comment above. For your second point/paragraph, then should some questions be moved there? It seems as though if you want to be the most helpful, you need to have an account in many places. Not sure about others but that spreads to too thin on tags I like. Is there a way to watch questions across the network then without having to check each?

Comment: There are some questions on SO that probably don't belong, yeah - unfortunately, there are a fair number of non-programmers who don't really grasp the distinction between using a website and writing programs that use an API. If you're interested in both, go here: http://stackexchange.com/filters/ - you can create a filter that captures questions from multiple tags across multiple sites (note that the Facebook subsite on SO includes questions in a number of different Facebook-related tags, not *just* [tag:facebook]).

Comment: Nice! I am not interested in FB at all, just used it as an easy example. I have set up a filter, which makes it handy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find questions on a common topic across all of the Stack Exchange sites, check out the "Filtered Questions" tool on http://stackexchange.com.

[image: modify filter screen]