# Where should small/home network questions be asked?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I have just asked a question on [How to assign different static IP addresses to the same machine depending on its OS on a network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/637059/how-to-assign-different-static-ip-addresses-to-the-same-machine-depending-on-its)

I read from this meta answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28230/253264 that suggested

> From a desktop support perspective there are certainly cases where a
>   large(r) number of machines will be affected by something, in which
>   case it's appropriate for SF. There are then others that are isolated
>   to a single computer, these tend to be the ones I vote to move to SU.

Since my question is clearly not about a single computer and is external to a single computer, I turned to ServerFault. I thought the question is about how to replicate a network admin strategy on my own (home) network. My question is, however, marked as off-topic, and I did see that homenetwork questions are off-topic. But this is not a single computer issue either.

My question is:

Where should such home/small network questions be asked?

What's the real difference between "professional" networks and the smaller networks that I build for my home or lab with a handful computers?

-- UPDATE --

The question asked here is different from the said duplicate question [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) as that question is about the difference among computer science and programming SE sites. It has nothing to do with network administration, whether it's large or small networks. None of the two SE sites in question (Server Fault and Super User) is even mentioned in the question or in the 2 cited answers.

-- UPDATE2 --

This question is not a duplicate of [What questions belong on Super User vs Server Fault?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/what-questions-belong-on-super-user-vs-server-fault), which was cited in the OP and was the cause of this question. That question does not cover the overlapping area of small networks, which could both be for work and for home network.

Comment: If you are managing the network as part of your **job** then it's Server Fault. If you are managing the network in your own time then it's Super User.

Comment: This really could be both cases, for a lab and for a home network. And it's illogical to determine what a question is depending on the occupation of the questioneer.

Comment: It's not a question of occupation - it's a question of *scale*. Configuring and administering a home network consisting of a few networked systems on a user-based operating system is vastly different from administering a corporate network involving hubs, routers, switches, servers, domains, user accounts, and so forth. If it's a home network, it's small scale and belongs on [su].

Comment: I pretty much doubt the `vast` difference from a network point of view. Also, many questions in Server Fault is about how to configure or partition disk for a single computer with Windows Server. I don't see the scale being an issue therein. Maybe this is just a culture/guild thing. But that's why I raised the question, and thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it comes down to wording and tools. As someone who is *definitely* a Super User regular and is familiar with Server Fault's norms, I'd say if it uses 'Enterprise' hardware - stuff made by Cisco, HP or Dell, its *probably* for SF (taking into account the minimal understanding close reason). DD WRT probably goes on Super User. Quite a few folk on SF also post or lurk on SU, so you're not likely to suffer answer qualitywise.

To confuse things there's *also* a [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not familiar with them.

With routers, the OS sitting on top matters a fair bit, so that should let you decide where to post it.

As an aside its unlikely an *enterprise* server system would dualboot, so it's clearly a dev or personal system, so once again, I'd lean towards SU.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification. `As an aside its unlikely an enterprise server system would dualboot.` The reason why my first thought was to go to SF (after reading the difference between SF & SU) is that, I was interested in how to manage those who dual-boot. I've seen my own dual-boot managed by several university level networks and got curious how someone could do that. Maybe they are not using dd-wrt at all. I didn't know there is a network engineering SE. Good to know.