# What is the difference between Server Fault and Super User

Tags: discussion, superuser, serverfault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any guidelines to find the “correct place”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/any-guidelines-to-find-the-correct-place)

Where can I find what questions are appropriate for Server Fault vs Super User ?

**UPDATED:** Is there a META-FAQ that covers all the sites?

Comment: I have a strange feeling this may be a duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read [here](https://superuser.com/faq) to learn more about SuperUser and [here](https://serverfault.com/faq) to learn more about Serverfault.

**SUPERUSER**
    *  computer hardware
    * computer software

**SERVERFAULT**
    *  servers
    * networks
    * many desktop PCs (other than your own)

Comment: and the color scheme!

Comment: @Evan, very true...  That may be where the only obvious difference comes and goes...  With the recent mod push to clean up superuser, the lines are blurred.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the FAQ for each site is a good start...