# Algorithm for finding the correct site/determining the off-topicness?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, off-topic, guidelines

Before asking the question I searched through Meta and found only [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/any-guidelines-to-find-the-correct-place) that seems to be a little bit outdated and not directly addressing my question.

I am not new to StackOverflow, but sometimes I have questions where I am not sure what site they should be posted too. I did read the FAQs of the most common technical forums like SO, Programmers, Code Review, Code Golf, Superuser etc, but I have never seen more or less an algorithmic/objective approach to defining if the question is suitable for the site or is rather an off-topic.

Of course I do understand that is not at all easy (if possible at all) to formulate the criteria in an objective and non-ambiguous way, but it would really help to see:

1. Some typical questions that are welcome in the community/forum.
2. Some (best if point-based) criteria for good question: quoting own source-code (let's say, 3 points), providing a web reference (1 point), providing own (eventually not complete or fully correct) approach to the problem etc.
3. Some typical off-topic questions with negative points, like: rhetorical question, no efforts done to find a solution on your own etc.

It would be also nice to have a kind of a sandbox for questions where everyone could post and then more experienced SO users could just move it to an appropriate technical (or non-technical) Stack Exchange site or close it altogether.

Answer (score 6):

An excellent "heuristic" is to check the faq for each of the sites.  All of them, but particularly [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), have an extensive list of what would be on topic or not.

A sandbox would be nice, but this would create work for users and moderators.  As it stands, mods are able to migrate (presuming the content is an excellent fit) to sites that users voting to close cannot.

There are also plenty of off-topic posts to learn from already in place.

Neat idea, but I think that most of the tools for this one are already available.